# How to fix a Pandas dataframes Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Not sure if my datetime column is a string, or what is going on with it.

Well I've tried sorting by quantity, then sorting by datetime, but it never get's it right.

Input

```
    print("kimera1")
    #with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  # more options can be specified also
    print(kimera)
    kimera = kimera.sort_values(by='quantity',ascending=False)
    print("kimera2")
    print(kimera)
    kimera = kimera.sort_values(by='date',ascending=True)
    print("kimera3")
    print(kimera)
```

output

```
kimera1
     client_id                       date  ...  type_id    unit_price
0   2114499871  2019-07-09T21:38:15+00:00  ...    37483  8.560000e+07
1     97005654  2019-07-09T08:07:57+00:00  ...       38  3.999900e+02
2     96644839  2019-07-07T02:02:45+00:00  ...    37457  2.900000e+07
3   2113806433  2019-07-06T18:13:12+00:00  ...    37482  7.300000e+07
4   1240358507  2019-07-05T19:38:20+00:00  ...    11381  4.399900e+07
5     97005654  2019-07-05T04:12:23+00:00  ...       38  3.999900e+02
6     97005654  2019-07-05T02:49:26+00:00  ...       38  3.999900e+02
7   1857838543  2019-07-03T20:08:15+00:00  ...    37482  6.900000e+07
8     92337897  2019-07-03T14:44:32+00:00  ...    11365  4.480000e+07
9   2114793091  2019-07-01T23:04:26+00:00  ...    12044  3.000000e+07
10    95826459  2019-06-30T07:22:45+00:00  ...    37482  1.190000e+08
11    94904480  2019-06-30T01:31:01+00:00  ...    11186  3.717800e+07
12  2113704258  2019-06-29T10:46:53+00:00  ...    12044  3.399700e+07
13  2115385566  2019-06-27T12:07:58+00:00  ...    11393  4.490000e+07
14  1732767131  2019-06-27T09:22:24+00:00  ...       38  3.252400e+02
15    93204128  2019-06-26T20:47:01+00:00  ...    11198  3.600000e+07
16    90216786  2019-06-25T23:51:48+00:00  ...    11172  3.600000e+07
17    91205905  2019-06-25T19:59:21+00:00  ...    16275  6.000000e+02
18  2113996003  2019-06-25T16:52:14+00:00  ...    11190  4.000000e+07
19    96345205  2019-06-25T16:39:49+00:00  ...    16275  6.000000e+02
20    95103814  2019-06-25T01:16:28+00:00  ...    11202  3.000000e+07
21   543983309  2019-06-24T14:05:49+00:00  ...    11172  2.741538e+07
22  2114159703  2019-06-23T21:20:04+00:00  ...       34  6.300000e+00
23  2114159703  2019-06-23T15:28:37+00:00  ...    16274  8.500000e+02
24  1872130440  2019-06-23T10:02:21+00:00  ...    11400  3.849900e+07
25  2112790910  2019-06-23T00:00:46+00:00  ...    11202  2.839450e+07
26  2115326382  2019-06-22T22:42:00+00:00  ...    11371  3.715019e+07
27    96768321  2019-06-22T17:02:14+00:00  ...    37481  8.900000e+07
28  1009077082  2019-06-21T23:35:03+00:00  ...    11379  4.200000e+07
29   755876330  2019-06-21T12:27:59+00:00  ...    11186  3.717800e+07
30  1556713165  2019-06-20T23:27:23+00:00  ...    11393  3.699800e+07
31   513171897  2019-06-19T15:58:51+00:00  ...    11381  4.381799e+07
32    96711003  2019-06-18T17:50:15+00:00  ...    11198  3.700000e+07
33   408059764  2019-06-18T15:36:49+00:00  ...    11172  3.500000e+07
34  1276544138  2019-06-17T21:32:47+00:00  ...    11379  4.100000e+07
35    94184713  2019-06-17T03:30:26+00:00  ...    37481  8.700000e+07
36  2113441660  2019-06-16T04:12:59+00:00  ...    37458  3.494900e+07
37   755284989  2019-06-15T19:54:44+00:00  ...    37458  3.500000e+07
38  1731319339  2019-06-13T12:00:14+00:00  ...    11379  4.200000e+07
39    96053157  2019-06-12T04:07:15+00:00  ...    37483  8.550000e+07
40  1690931127  2019-06-12T00:44:40+00:00  ...    37482  6.170000e+07
41    92812153  2019-06-11T05:23:09+00:00  ...    37460  3.650000e+07
42  2114791711  2019-06-10T16:14:59+00:00  ...    11371  4.150000e+07
43  1547875730  2019-06-10T15:22:53+00:00  ...    17887  9.999900e+02
44   227535700  2019-06-10T15:12:06+00:00  ...    16272  5.445000e+02
45    95165645  2019-06-10T06:32:52+00:00  ...    11393  5.399000e+07
46  1859791498  2019-06-10T05:35:57+00:00  ...    22460  6.200000e+07
47  2112629749  2019-06-09T15:46:46+00:00  ...     2549  1.800000e+06
48    94391975  2019-06-08T00:06:12+00:00  ...    37460  3.650000e+07
49    91521700  2019-06-07T14:11:45+00:00  ...    11393  4.999800e+07
50  1171184159  2019-06-06T18:10:19+00:00  ...    12044  3.399800e+07
51    96410073  2019-06-05T17:32:01+00:00  ...    11371  4.700000e+07

[52 rows x 10 columns]
kimera2
     client_id                       date  ...  type_id    unit_price
22  2114159703  2019-06-23T21:20:04+00:00  ...       34  6.300000e+00
44   227535700  2019-06-10T15:12:06+00:00  ...    16272  5.445000e+02
43  1547875730  2019-06-10T15:22:53+00:00  ...    17887  9.999900e+02
19    96345205  2019-06-25T16:39:49+00:00  ...    16275  6.000000e+02
17    91205905  2019-06-25T19:59:21+00:00  ...    16275  6.000000e+02
23  2114159703  2019-06-23T15:28:37+00:00  ...    16274  8.500000e+02
14  1732767131  2019-06-27T09:22:24+00:00  ...       38  3.252400e+02
5     97005654  2019-07-05T04:12:23+00:00  ...       38  3.999900e+02
6     97005654  2019-07-05T02:49:26+00:00  ...       38  3.999900e+02
1     97005654  2019-07-09T08:07:57+00:00  ...       38  3.999900e+02
34  1276544138  2019-06-17T21:32:47+00:00  ...    11379  4.100000e+07
35    94184713  2019-06-17T03:30:26+00:00  ...    37481  8.700000e+07
38  1731319339  2019-06-13T12:00:14+00:00  ...    11379  4.200000e+07
33   408059764  2019-06-18T15:36:49+00:00  ...    11172  3.500000e+07
36  2113441660  2019-06-16T04:12:59+00:00  ...    37458  3.494900e+07
37   755284989  2019-06-15T19:54:44+00:00  ...    37458  3.500000e+07
32    96711003  2019-06-18T17:50:15+00:00  ...    11198  3.700000e+07
0   2114499871  2019-07-09T21:38:15+00:00  ...    37483  8.560000e+07
40  1690931127  2019-06-12T00:44:40+00:00  ...    37482  6.170000e+07
39    96053157  2019-06-12T04:07:15+00:00  ...    37483  8.550000e+07
30  1556713165  2019-06-20T23:27:23+00:00  ...    11393  3.699800e+07
41    92812153  2019-06-11T05:23:09+00:00  ...    37460  3.650000e+07
42  2114791711  2019-06-10T16:14:59+00:00  ...    11371  4.150000e+07
45    95165645  2019-06-10T06:32:52+00:00  ...    11393  5.399000e+07
46  1859791498  2019-06-10T05:35:57+00:00  ...    22460  6.200000e+07
47  2112629749  2019-06-09T15:46:46+00:00  ...     2549  1.800000e+06
48    94391975  2019-06-08T00:06:12+00:00  ...    37460  3.650000e+07
49    91521700  2019-06-07T14:11:45+00:00  ...    11393  4.999800e+07
50  1171184159  2019-06-06T18:10:19+00:00  ...    12044  3.399800e+07
31   513171897  2019-06-19T15:58:51+00:00  ...    11381  4.381799e+07
26  2115326382  2019-06-22T22:42:00+00:00  ...    11371  3.715019e+07
29   755876330  2019-06-21T12:27:59+00:00  ...    11186  3.717800e+07
12  2113704258  2019-06-29T10:46:53+00:00  ...    12044  3.399700e+07
2     96644839  2019-07-07T02:02:45+00:00  ...    37457  2.900000e+07
3   2113806433  2019-07-06T18:13:12+00:00  ...    37482  7.300000e+07
4   1240358507  2019-07-05T19:38:20+00:00  ...    11381  4.399900e+07
7   1857838543  2019-07-03T20:08:15+00:00  ...    37482  6.900000e+07
8     92337897  2019-07-03T14:44:32+00:00  ...    11365  4.480000e+07
9   2114793091  2019-07-01T23:04:26+00:00  ...    12044  3.000000e+07
10    95826459  2019-06-30T07:22:45+00:00  ...    37482  1.190000e+08
11    94904480  2019-06-30T01:31:01+00:00  ...    11186  3.717800e+07
13  2115385566  2019-06-27T12:07:58+00:00  ...    11393  4.490000e+07
28  1009077082  2019-06-21T23:35:03+00:00  ...    11379  4.200000e+07
15    93204128  2019-06-26T20:47:01+00:00  ...    11198  3.600000e+07
16    90216786  2019-06-25T23:51:48+00:00  ...    11172  3.600000e+07
18  2113996003  2019-06-25T16:52:14+00:00  ...    11190  4.000000e+07
20    95103814  2019-06-25T01:16:28+00:00  ...    11202  3.000000e+07
21   543983309  2019-06-24T14:05:49+00:00  ...    11172  2.741538e+07
24  1872130440  2019-06-23T10:02:21+00:00  ...    11400  3.849900e+07
25  2112790910  2019-06-23T00:00:46+00:00  ...    11202  2.839450e+07
27    96768321  2019-06-22T17:02:14+00:00  ...    37481  8.900000e+07
51    96410073  2019-06-05T17:32:01+00:00  ...    11371  4.700000e+07

[52 rows x 10 columns]
kimera3
     client_id                       date  ...  type_id    unit_price
0   2114499871  2019-07-09T21:38:15+00:00  ...    37483  8.560000e+07
1     97005654  2019-07-09T08:07:57+00:00  ...       38  3.999900e+02
2     96644839  2019-07-07T02:02:45+00:00  ...    37457  2.900000e+07
3   2113806433  2019-07-06T18:13:12+00:00  ...    37482  7.300000e+07
4   1240358507  2019-07-05T19:38:20+00:00  ...    11381  4.399900e+07
5     97005654  2019-07-05T04:12:23+00:00  ...       38  3.999900e+02
6     97005654  2019-07-05T02:49:26+00:00  ...       38  3.999900e+02
7   1857838543  2019-07-03T20:08:15+00:00  ...    37482  6.900000e+07
8     92337897  2019-07-03T14:44:32+00:00  ...    11365  4.480000e+07
9   2114793091  2019-07-01T23:04:26+00:00  ...    12044  3.000000e+07
10    95826459  2019-06-30T07:22:45+00:00  ...    37482  1.190000e+08
11    94904480  2019-06-30T01:31:01+00:00  ...    11186  3.717800e+07
12  2113704258  2019-06-29T10:46:53+00:00  ...    12044  3.399700e+07
13  2115385566  2019-06-27T12:07:58+00:00  ...    11393  4.490000e+07
14  1732767131  2019-06-27T09:22:24+00:00  ...       38  3.252400e+02
15    93204128  2019-06-26T20:47:01+00:00  ...    11198  3.600000e+07
16    90216786  2019-06-25T23:51:48+00:00  ...    11172  3.600000e+07
17    91205905  2019-06-25T19:59:21+00:00  ...    16275  6.000000e+02
18  2113996003  2019-06-25T16:52:14+00:00  ...    11190  4.000000e+07
19    96345205  2019-06-25T16:39:49+00:00  ...    16275  6.000000e+02
20    95103814  2019-06-25T01:16:28+00:00  ...    11202  3.000000e+07
21   543983309  2019-06-24T14:05:49+00:00  ...    11172  2.741538e+07
22  2114159703  2019-06-23T21:20:04+00:00  ...       34  6.300000e+00
23  2114159703  2019-06-23T15:28:37+00:00  ...    16274  8.500000e+02
24  1872130440  2019-06-23T10:02:21+00:00  ...    11400  3.849900e+07
25  2112790910  2019-06-23T00:00:46+00:00  ...    11202  2.839450e+07
26  2115326382  2019-06-22T22:42:00+00:00  ...    11371  3.715019e+07
27    96768321  2019-06-22T17:02:14+00:00  ...    37481  8.900000e+07
28  1009077082  2019-06-21T23:35:03+00:00  ...    11379  4.200000e+07
29   755876330  2019-06-21T12:27:59+00:00  ...    11186  3.717800e+07
30  1556713165  2019-06-20T23:27:23+00:00  ...    11393  3.699800e+07
31   513171897  2019-06-19T15:58:51+00:00  ...    11381  4.381799e+07
32    96711003  2019-06-18T17:50:15+00:00  ...    11198  3.700000e+07
33   408059764  2019-06-18T15:36:49+00:00  ...    11172  3.500000e+07
34  1276544138  2019-06-17T21:32:47+00:00  ...    11379  4.100000e+07
35    94184713  2019-06-17T03:30:26+00:00  ...    37481  8.700000e+07
36  2113441660  2019-06-16T04:12:59+00:00  ...    37458  3.494900e+07
37   755284989  2019-06-15T19:54:44+00:00  ...    37458  3.500000e+07
38  1731319339  2019-06-13T12:00:14+00:00  ...    11379  4.200000e+07
39    96053157  2019-06-12T04:07:15+00:00  ...    37483  8.550000e+07
40  1690931127  2019-06-12T00:44:40+00:00  ...    37482  6.170000e+07
41    92812153  2019-06-11T05:23:09+00:00  ...    37460  3.650000e+07
42  2114791711  2019-06-10T16:14:59+00:00  ...    11371  4.150000e+07
43  1547875730  2019-06-10T15:22:53+00:00  ...    17887  9.999900e+02
44   227535700  2019-06-10T15:12:06+00:00  ...    16272  5.445000e+02
45    95165645  2019-06-10T06:32:52+00:00  ...    11393  5.399000e+07
46  1859791498  2019-06-10T05:35:57+00:00  ...    22460  6.200000e+07
51    96410073  2019-06-05T17:32:01+00:00  ...    11371  4.700000e+07
50  1171184159  2019-06-06T18:10:19+00:00  ...    12044  3.399800e+07
49    91521700  2019-06-07T14:11:45+00:00  ...    11393  4.999800e+07
48    94391975  2019-06-08T00:06:12+00:00  ...    37460  3.650000e+07
47  2112629749  2019-06-09T15:46:46+00:00  ...     2549  1.800000e+06

[52 rows x 10 columns]
```

The data orgininally was in the right order, newest at the top, oldest at the bottom, that's the way the data comes out of the server.
But I want to be able to sort it back to that if I ever for example sorted it by quantity.
It comes close, but the last 5 are really screwed up, not sure why.
So apparently if the datatime is a string, I need to convert it to a proper pandas.to_datetime, if I'm understanding correctly, not even sure if that's right.
And if it is right I'm not sure how to start.

Answer (score 0):

To be double sure, convert date to datetime type if it's in string format:

```
kimera['date'] = pd.to_datetime(kimera['date'], errors='coerce')
```

Then do this:

```
kimera = kimera.sort_values(['quantity', 'date'], ascending = [False, True])
```

Comment: in to_datetime, `errors='coerce'` will be  helpful for the op, as it will show the errors.

Comment: So I tried this ```kimera['date'] = pd.to_datetime(kimera['date'], errors='coerce')``` and it returned ```<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType'>``` as the new type.

Comment: Every single row had NaT as the new entry under the date column accept for index's 47 to 51, they remained unchanged.

Comment: I don't get the second line of code, I wasn't trying to do two kinds of sorting at the same time, I just sorted it to quantity as an example that sorting it by date was currently impossible, just wanted to sort it correctly by date, that's all.

Comment: I took the first few rows of your DF from the date column, and it worked fine when I converted it to datetime type. Could you please post the output of kimera.info()?

Comment: ``` <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 52 entries, 0 to 51
Data columns (total 10 columns):
client_id         52 non-null int64
date              52 non-null object
is_buy            52 non-null bool
is_personal       52 non-null bool
journal_ref_id    52 non-null int64
location_id       52 non-null int64
quantity          52 non-null int64
transaction_id    52 non-null int64
type_id           52 non-null int64
unit_price        52 non-null float64
dtypes: bool(2), float64(1), int64(6), object(1)
memory usage: 3.4+ KB
```

Comment: What do you get if you remove the errors= 'coerce': kimera['date'] = pd.to_datetime(kimera['date'])

Comment: like this? "kimera['date'] = pd.to_datetime(kimera['date'])" it errored out with "TypeError: <class 'pyswagger.primitives._time.Datetime'> is not convertible to datetime"

Comment: Could you please do this first: kimera['date'] = kimera['date'].str.strip(), and then do: kimera['date'] = pd.to_datetime(kimera['date'], errors='coerce')

Comment: Input ```kimera['date'] = kimera['date'].str.strip()
      kimera['date'] = pd.to_datetime(kimera['date'], errors='coerce')
      print(kimera)```

Comment: client_id                      date  ...  type_id    unit_price
41    92812153                       NaT  ...    37460  3.650000e+07
42  2114791711 2019-06-10 16:14:59+00:00  ...    11371  4.150000e+07
43  1547875730 2019-06-10 15:22:53+00:00  ...    17887  9.999900e+02
44   227535700 2019-06-10 15:12:06+00:00  ...    16272  5.445000e+02
45    95165645 2019-06-10 06:32:52+00:00  ...    11393  5.399000e+07

[52 rows x 10 columns]

Comment: I had to remove most of the lines from the output, to many characters, but line 41 and everything above it had the NaT, 42 and everything below it had the datatime, or what looks like a datetime to me.

Comment: If this is looking to difficult we can leave it, and I'll just avoid doing anything that resorts it, I could just have another program open the CSV file, copy what's there, and resort that, thus hopefully forever keeping the lines in their correct order.